# Multiple functions, return is false but form still submitting

Tags: javascript

Creating a form,

I have 2 functions

```
function myValidation() {
   valName();
   idChange();
}
input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return myValidation();"
```

But when there are still errors my form submits, but when I put them separately (but not together) in onclick, they work fine and don't submit when there are errors.

Comment: add event.preventDefault() in myValidation function

Comment: do `valName` and `idChange` individually `return false`, as you mention it but none of your code actually does return `false` anywhere.  `myValidation` implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: You are calling the functions `valName` and `idChange` but not using their return values in the `myValidation` function. Try `return valName() && idChange();`

Comment: @AjuJohn wow thank you this worked!

Comment: @josh - watch out, that will work in some browsers and not others.

Comment: @josh oh yes I see. damn ok i'll try the other solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the return values of your `valName` and `idChange` functions in your `myValidation` function and so it will return nothing.

Just adjust your function so it uses them.

```
function myValidation() {
    return valName() && idChange();
}
```

That being said, there are sometimes issues with the approach of returning false on an onclick event that are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false).

Comment: By any chance are you Marcelo Alves?

Comment: Hi marcelo thanks for the reply, I tried the following but it seems like idChange does not work when I do this but valName does work, That being said If I switch the functions then idChange works but valName doesn't idChange() && valName()

Comment: @Reddy No, I am not.

Comment: @josh Are these functions doing more than just figuring out a return value? In this approach, the functions get called in order until one of them returns false. After that any remaining functions are skipped. If you need to have all the functions be called regardless then you can modify the code to this: http://codepen.io/marceloa/pen/LNxPwX?editors=1010

Answer (score -1):

Try both lines. They will work in all browsers.

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```